# Reading a truth table in from plain text, translating it to a map<int,list<int>> in C++

Tags: c++, list, file-io, dictionary

I'm writing a file parser for standard C++ (no third-parties like Boost, unfortunately)...

I'm dealing with a situation where I have a plain-text file formatted like this:

```
1 ..header line 1, unimportant
2 ..header line 2, unimportant
3 ..header line 3, unimportant
4         1        0        0        0        0        0        0        1
5         2        0        1        0        2        1        0        0
  ...skipping ahead
14       11        1        0        0        0        0        1        1
15       12        0        0        1        0        0        1        2
16       13        2        0        0        0        1        0        0
  ...etc
```

(Note: The first column, 1 - 16, are line numbers. The skip ahead is meant to represent the gap of 8 spaces from the start of each line gets shorter as the second column, 1- 13, gets longer and longer numbers.

This text file denotes a truth table whereby items must be grouped by the columns, and each group will be composed of corresponding numbers from the first column. For instance, by the end of parsing *this* example, a map of type `<int, list<int>>` should look like (assuming there are no `truths` between lines 6 and 13):

```
[1: {11, 13}]
[2: {5, 15}]
[3: {12}]
[4: {5}]
[5: {5,16}]
[6: {14,15}]
[7: {4,14,15}]
```

In general, the number of columns in the text file can change, meaning the number of groups will change, so this must be accounted for. The number of rows is also variable, but will both will always start at `1` and the columns will *not* be numbered (but we can do that ourselves).

Now, were I to do this in Java I'd have a working solution rather quickly. However, I've never done work in C++ and am having trouble figuring out how to perform the operations properly, between its different structures and syntax. Despite scouring and finding lots of good guides, my lack of C++ foundation makes it hard to understand even the syntax differences that, I speculate, must be very basic.

Still, I've designed procedure, and it should work according to the following pseudocode:

```
//Begin Parse
    //Create filereader "strmFileIn"

    //To get past the first three lines, which will always be needless header info
    string dummyLine;
    for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
        getline(strmFileIn, strDummyLine);

    //Read first line to get count of how many groups are present
    //(Copied from internet: gets the first line and puts the cursor back at its start)
    int startPos = strmFileIn.tellg();
    string strFirstLine;
    getline(strmFileIn, strFirstLine);
    strmFileIn.seekg(startPos, std::ios_base::beg);
    //Tokenize strFirstLine into Array<int> tempArray
    int numGroups = tempArray.size() - 1 //accounting for the row-header column, 1 - 13

    //Create map (going to use java syntax, sorry)
    Map<int,list<int>> myMap = new Map<int,list<int>>;

    //Populate map with ints and empty lists (java again, sorry)
    for (int i = 1; i <= numGroups; i++)
        myMap.put(i, new List<int>);

    //Iterate over lines in the file and appropriately populate the map's lists
    while (fileIn != eof)
    {
        string fileInLine;
        getline(strmFileIn, fileInLine);
        //Tokenize fileInLine into Array<int> tempFileInArray
        int intElemID = tempFileInArray[0];
        //Remove element [0] from tempFileInArray (will be the row number, 1 - 13

        //Iterate over remaining items in tempFileInArray, affect myMap where necessary
        for (int i = 1; int i <= groupNum; i++)
            if (tempFileInArray[i] != 0) //is not a strict truth-table, as any nonzero will be a truth
                myMap.get[i].add(intElemID);
    }

    //Remove any entries in myMap with empty lists

    //Kill strmFileIn for memory's sake
//End Parse
```

As you can see, my code is a broken mix of pseudocode and comparable Java I've already figured out. I just don't know how to turn this into C++; even with similar data structures, the syntax is a little daunting to someone with no experience. Is anyone here willing to help me out with it?

I really appreciate any insight.

Comment: It's not Java code, is it C#?  I don't think pseudo-Java is worth having as a tag.

Comment: Maybe i just don't understand your example, but isn't your result using the line numbers instead of the values in the first column?

Comment: Why do you need to write this in a language you don't know? Why not just write it in Java?

Comment: @JosephMansfield The line numbers are not actually part of the file-- They're just there to represent that the first actual colum (1 - 13) does *not* represent line numbers

Comment: @jalf Because I've been brought in on a legacy project that is written in C++, and unlike the academic world, the corporate world is very much "learn-by-dropping-you-into-it", unfortunately.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I may have messed up some of the java code, but in reality the entire example should be taken as pseudocode anyway because, as I typed it in this window, there are likely a host of syntax errors that would leave it invalid as far as Java goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems overly complicated, so lets do this one step at a time.  Additionally, neither your code nor file format show how many bool columns should exist on each row, so I've ignored that part for this answer.

But first, a tip: In C++, the containers you care about 99.99% of the time are `std::unordered_map`, `std::vector`, and in very rare cases, `std::map`, `boost::stable_vector` and `std::deque`.  In your case, you have rows with sequential indices, and the data for each row appears to be better stored as a vector of booleans.  However, we'll do it your way, with the replacement of `std::vector` instead of `std::list`, and `std::unordered_map` instead of `std::map`.

This major data structures are mostly obvious:

```
std::unordered_map<int,std::vector<int>> myMap;
std::ifstream strmFileIn("input_file.txt");
```

Next your code reads in the first line, then ignores it entirely.  I have no idea why, so I'll skip over that.  Then, we parse out the lines one by one:

```
std::string full_current_line;
//for as long as we can read more lines, read them in
while(std::getline(strmFileIn, full_current_line) 
{
    //make the line into a stream so that we can parse data out
    std::stringstream cur_line_stream(full_current_line);
    //read in the line identifier
    int identifier = 0;
    cur_line_stream >> identifier;
    //if that failed, abort.
    if (!cur_line_stream)
    {
        //invalid identifer!
        std::cerr << "identifier is invalid!\n"; //report
        strmFileIn.setstate(std::ios::failbit); //failed to parse the data
        break; //do not continue this loop
    }
```

After that, we parse out the data for each row, which is surprisingly simple:

```
    int column = 0;
    int is_true = false;
    //for each number remaining in the row...
    while(cur_line_stream >> is_true) 
    {
        //hooray we read a column!
        ++column;

        if (is_true ==0)
        {
            //if it's zero, skip it
        } 
        else if (is_true == 1)
        { 
            //get the data for this column, and add this row's identifier
            //myMap[column] will create a new empty entry if it didn't exist yet
            //NOTE: This syntax only creates when used with map and unordered_map.
            //      This syntax does NOT create for vector and deque.
            //once we have the vector, we push_back the new identifier into it.
            myMap[column].push_back(identifier);
        }
        else
        {
            //invalid data!
            std::cerr << is_true << " is invalid!  found on row " << identifier << '\n';
            cur_line_stream.setstate(std::ios::failbit); //failed to parse the data
            strmFileIn.setstate(std::ios::failbit); //failed to parse the data
            break; //do not continue this loop
        }
    }
}
```

If you know that `groupNum` contained the number of bools, you could replace that second `while` with something more like you already have:

```
    for (int i = 1; int i <= groupNum; i++)
    {
        cur_line_stream >> is_true;
        //if that failed, abort
        if (!cur_line_stream) 
        {
            //invalid data!
            std::cerr << "data could not be read on row " << identifier << '\n';
            cur_line_stream.setstate(std::ios::failbit); //failed to parse the data
            strmFileIn.setstate(std::ios::failbit); //failed to parse the data
            break; //do not continue this loop
        }
        else if (is_true == 0) 
        {
            //if it's zero, skip it
        }
        etc etc etc
```

Comment: I like a lot of what you say, however I'm confused on a few things. Let me first explain your question on why I'm skipping lines. First, obviously, I'm skipping the top 3 lines. They have no useful data, ever. Second, I'm not exactly skipping the first line. Maybe the calls I'm making are, but I put them in there thinking that they will [Set strmFileIn current point],[store first line],[return strmFileIn to aforementioned point]. I'm doing this because, since we don't know how many columns there are, this is merely how we determine how many entries will be in `myMap`.

Comment: Next, the things I'm confused about here. First, we've declared the `unorderedmap` and `ifstream` ( I assume "input file stream" ). But, we never populate `myMap` with anything. Later on, we refer to it as we perform `myMap[i].push_back(identifier)`, but to my eye we haven't even put anything in there yet. Am I missing something?

Another confusion is, where are we incrementing `column`?

Finally, might be my mistake, but, by `# of bools` you're referring to the number of ints on each row, right? While they can be bools, they are at the moment `int`, and are addressed in my code and file.

Comment: @jwarner112: Your code indeed does read the first line, and then reset, but then ignores the first line.  If you deleted those lines, the code in the question would behave exactly the same, but faster.  Since I could not deduce their intent, I can't "fix" them.

Comment: @jwarner112: Yes, `ifstream` is "input file stream".  `myMap` is a empty mapping of integers to empty vectors, which is a good place to start.  `myMap[i]` _is_ confusing, because in `map` `unorderd_map` _only_, this functionality creates a new entry.  I'll add a comment about that.  Good call on `column`, I forgot to increment.  Yes, I refer to them as bools in the comments (since they hold truth values), but in code I've only referred to them as `int`, just like you did.

Comment: Oh! I understand the confusion right now. I've been using `//` to denote both an actual code comment and an intermediate step. Between the "get line and return" code and the "tempArray" code, I in fact create `tempArray`, composed of the tokenized string captured during `getline`. My fault for using unclear notation.

And thank you for your hard work in helping me solve this. I'm right now adapting the code you gave (variable names and whatnot), to see if I can get it to compile.

Comment: Thanks for your help with this, I've got it parsing properly now. Some changes I had to make to your code to suit my own purposes:

 - Remove some of the catches like `std::cerr`-- I've got in-house handlers for that.
 - Missing parens on the outer `while` loop
 - Replaced `else if` with `else`, removed other `else` (I only need to handle cases for `0` and `!0`)


I thank you profusely for helping me achieve a working solution, and in the process, teaching me a lot about C++ and its syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Work the other way. Code only in C++ (not in Java and don't think in Java), but start by parsing a small chunk of your syntax. First, code the [lexer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis). Test it. Then code the [parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parser#Parser), probably a [recursive descent parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser), and test it on short simple subelements of your language. Perhaps you'll need some small [look-ahead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing#Lookahead) (an easy task, use a `std::list<Token>`) Keep going up.

Start by formalizing, with pencil and paper, your input language. Could you for instance write a simple [BNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form) grammar for it? (your question does not explain what is the input, it just gives an example)

In C++ parlance: to parse a `map<int,list<int>>` you certainly need to be able to parse `int` and `list<int>`. So write first the parsers for these.

As commented by [Mooing Duck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/845092/mooing-duck), your input language (which you did not define, just gave an example) seems simple enough to avoid most of this. But still, the idea is the same, think directly in C++ and start by reading a simple subpart of the input. Test your code. When that works, increase the part that is accepted. Repeat all this.

Comment: A recursive descent parser?  Did you look at the example?  The grammar hardly justifies that complexity.  Even a lexer is overkill for this.

Comment: Agreed, but the OP is stuck. My method would certainly guide him, even if it might be overkill.

Comment: The thing about guiding someone who is stuck is generally to guide them *towards a solution*. Writing a friggin' compiler isn't really a solution to the OP's problem.

Comment: I'm confused as to why everyone else doesn't understand the input languages-- maybe I used ambiguous terms? The parser will be written in standard C++ and the input file will be plain-text, as if a .txt file were renamed with an arbitrary file format. Also, you tell me to think in C++ but I'm not sure I can do this. I lack a foundational knowledge in C++ and so while I can think in general Computer Science terms and in Java terms, as I have some background, I wouldn't know where to begin thinking strictly in C++. @MooingDuck's example has a lot of syntax usage that helps me, though.

Comment: There are many formalizations for syntax (notably BNF). You should use them. Formalizing the input language is part of the problem solving.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very simple solution that uses nothing but C++ and standard libraries.  It just reads line by line and pulls each element out of the line with stream extraction using `operator>>`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <map>
#include <list>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // Parse command line
    if( argc != 2 )
        return 1;
    std::fstream fin(argv[1]);
    if( !fin.good() )
    {
        std::cerr << "Error opening file for reading: " << argv[1] << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    // Skip first three lines
    std::string line;
    for( int i=0; i<3; ++i )
    {
        std::getline(fin, line);
    }

    // Read each line
    std::map<int, std::list<int> > hits;
    while( std::getline(fin, line) )
    {
        // Extract each element from the line
        std::stringstream sstr(line);

        // Read line number from first column
        int linenum = 0;
        sstr >> linenum;

        // Interpret remaining columns as truth values
        bool truth;
        int col=1;
        while( sstr >> truth )
        {
            // Store position in map if true
            if( truth )
            {
                hits[col].push_back(linenum);
            }
            col++;
        }
    }

    // Print results
    std::map<int, std::list<int> >::const_iterator col_iter;
    for( col_iter = hits.begin(); col_iter != hits.end(); ++col_iter )
    {
        std::cout << "[" << col_iter->first << ": {";
        std::list<int>::const_iterator line_iter;
        for( line_iter = col_iter->second.begin(); line_iter != col_iter->second.end(); ++line_iter )
        {
            std::cout << *line_iter << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "} ]" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```